# Trigger Snackbar on external file creation/update

Tags: json, angular, snackbar, read-data

I am a newbie. in Angular, I have implemented a snackbar where click event triggers it for 3 seconds. This however is not what I exactly need. I am to receive values from a Python code in JSON/text form. As soon as the file is recieved/changed, it should trigger the snackbar with file content displayed, preferably with minimal computational load. Since same value is allowed to be received one after the other, I am thinking after receiving the value of file I should delete the file and detect recreation. Since file is quite large, I will copy relevant portion below

In the .ts file I have

```
  import { CustomSnackBarComponent } from '../custom-snack-bar/custom-snack-bar.component';

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private snackBar : MatSnackBar) { }

  openCustomSnackBar(){
  this.snackBar.openFromComponent(CustomSnackBarComponent, {duration: 3000})
  }
```

In template

```
<button mat-button (click) = "openCustomSnackBar()"> Click </button>
```

and the custom-snack-bar.component.html contains

text

Can someone please tell me how I can do this

Comment: Have you tried with a service promise. If you have a server and you receive the data from it after the data is received you could trigger openCustomSnachBar(). Look Angular service and observable.

Comment: Thanks! Not yet, but I will look into it